# Phone Keeps Going to Sleep

Tags: 7.1-nougat, sleep

My phone keeps going to sleep within a minute or so despite the fact that it is set to not go to sleep for 10 minutes. Why is it doing this? This is an Asus ZenFone Live V running Android 7.1.1.

To be more clear, the screen goes black and locks shortly thereafter in about a minute. I'm not sure this is technically sleep mode, but it is sure annoying to have to unlock every time something steals your attention for a minute.

Comment: Where did it set that it doesn't go to sleep? Is it under *settings > display > sleep > 10 min*?

Comment: Yes, there exactly

Comment: Check under settings > lock screen > lock time. Sometimes if the lock time is less then the sleep time, then the screen will go to sleep at that time. Basically, if sleep time is 5 min, but lock the is 2 min, then the phone will go to sleep at 2 min. Let me know if that's true for your phone

Comment: It has an auto lock setting that is also set to 10 minutes.

Comment: Is this phone connected to a corporate email account or used as a device for business use? If so, it may have a VPN with corporate guildelines to adhere to, which conflict or override personal preferences. Check for a device administrator you recognize as belonging to your company.

Comment: Nope. Just my personal.

Comment: Any automation tools installed like Tasker or Llama? I know Llama best, so I can speak to profiles it uses, which control environmental attributes as it enters/leaves known areas via wifi, or control towers, etc. Anything like that inadvertently making setting changes?

Comment: For some reason my last comment didn't go through, so I forgot about this.  Automation tools were installed after the problem began.